# база данных не выводит из таблицы значения нового пользователя , хотя если тот не был в базе - его записало ,значит значения ДОЛЖНЫ быть

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord, бот

```
const platform = require("discord.js")
const mst = require("mysql2")
const db = mst.createConnection({
    host: "секрет",
    user: "секрет",
    password: "секрет",
    database: "секрет",
    multipleStatements: true
})
db.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS state(who TEXT,coordinatex INT,coordinatey INT,vs TEXT,busy TEXT,free INT)`)
let way = new platform.Client({
    intents: [platform.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, platform.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, platform.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent]
})
way.on("messageCreate",(letter)=>{
    sender = letter.author.id
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM state WHERE who=?`,[sender],function (a,b,c){
        if(typeof(b[0])=="undefined"){
            console.log(`какой-то ноу нейм`)
            db.query(`INSERT INTO state VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)`,[sender,1,1,"нет","ничего",0])
        }
    })
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM state WHERE who=?`,[sender],function (d,e,f){
        console.log(`айди: ${e[0].who}`)
    })
})
way.login("секрет")
```

Comment: console.log(`какой-то ноу нейм`) этот консоль лог отрабатывает?

Comment: ввод в таблицу state происходит но когда срабатывает select то бд орёт на то что таких данных нету и пытается взять нулевой индекс от undefined